# Image Get's warped upon splitting it into parts

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to cut images into equal parts, but whenever I try to get them to display, their dimensions seem to have warped. Every part of the image, with the exception of the first, is squished.
In the following image, you see an example of the result I get on the left, compared to the image That the code uses to make the parts, on the right.
(There are four pictureboxes on the left, stored in a panel)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EX8F.png)

this image has been cut into 4 parts, but the right and bottom side both seem to have been flattened, and this I don't want.

I used the following code for this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        
        Image img = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
        List<Image> MultipleImages = new List<Image>();
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                int imgPartWidth = img.Width / 2;
                int imgPartHeight = img.Height / 2;
                MultipleImages.Add(new Bitmap(img.Width / 2, img.Height / 2));
                var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(MultipleImages[index]);

                int PartSetupWidth = img.Width / 2;
                int PartSetupHeight = img.Height / 2;
                int PartSourceX1 = i * imgPartWidth;
                int PartSourceY1 = j * imgPartHeight;
                int PartSourceX2 = (i + 1) * imgPartWidth;
                int PartSourceY2 = (j + 1) * imgPartHeight;



                graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, PartSetupWidth, PartSetupHeight),
                                   new Rectangle(PartSourceX1, PartSourceY1, PartSourceX2, PartSourceY2), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                graphics.Dispose();
                index++;
            }
        }

        int index2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Height = 100;
                pb.Width = 100;
                pb.Image = MultipleImages[index2];
                pb.Location = new Point(i * 100, j * 100);
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                index2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```